# How to apply fq on a nested query in solr?

Tags: solr, subquery

Currently i have the following query:
/select?qf=kw_exact_test_bool2 kw_broad_test_bool2 kw_negative_test_bool2&rows=200&debugQuery=true&fl=*&q={!dismax qf=kw_negative_test_bool2 qf=kw_broad_test_bool2 qf=kw_exact_test_bool2 fq=$collapseQuery}dress&cache=false&collapseQuery={!collapse field=adset_id max=cscore()}

with documents looking like this:
{
kw_broad_test_bool2: text,
adset_id: number
}
{
kw_exact_test_bool2: text,
adset_id: number
}
{
kw_negative_test_bool2: text,
adset_id: number
}

and from what i see in the debugger, solr does not apply the fq condition in my subquery.
As a result of this query: i want to get only the keyword with the biggest score per adset (note that the reason i am not applying the collapse in the main fq parameter is because i want to apply the condition there to exclude the negative keywords)